# Combining compound operators

Tags: c, operators

I'm only a casual user of C, when programming for micros like Arduino, but I'm interested in bettering my understanding of the vernacular.

I know that you can shorthand things like `x = x % 10` to `x %= 10`, and `x = x + 1` to `x += 1`. But I couldn't wrap my head around compounding both parts of this:

`x = (x + 1) % 10`

If that's possible, what does it look like? 
`(x += 1) %= 10` ? That seems... if not wrong, then confusing.

Comment: I get that you're just trying to understand; that's excellent and I don't want to criticize you for it, but IMHO it's worth mentioning that, especially when working in unsafe languages like C, you shouldn't try to make your code as terse as possible.  The easier the code is to understand the less likely there will be bugs.  In this case, there is nothing wrong with `x = (x + 1) % 10`.  It's probably the clearest and most natural way to write what you want, which pretty much means it's The Right Way.

Comment: @nemequ - I agree, and that's the code I used. You caught the spirit of the question, which was sparked by mere curiosity. I figure that if I have such a question others might too, which is what this site as about, eh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `(x += 1) %= 10` is not legal in C.  The result of an assignment operator, whether `=` or one of the compound assignment operators, is not a lvalue.  Loosely speaking, this means it can't appear on the left side of an assignment.

That statement would have to be broken up in two parts:

```
x += 1;
x %= 10;
```

As an aside, `(x += 1) %= 10` *is* valid in C++.

Comment: Thanks. I'd likely not use it in either place, I was just curious. In a way it's too bad that it works in one and not the other.

Answer (score 0):

Just try `x += 1; x %= 10;` as an alternative, it will work, but it is not equivalent to the first expression.  You cannot wrap both in a single expression[1] as

```
x op= expression;
```

means

```
x = x op (expression);  /* look at the parenthesis */
```

and that forces the evaluation of the expression first.  The only case in which

```
x = (x op1 a) op2 b;
```

could be converted to an op-assign operation is if the operators are associative and the expression can be converted to:

```
x = x op1 (a op2 b);
```

(or if `op2` has higher precedence than `op1`, which means the evaluation order is as above) and then

```
x op1= a op2 b;
```

would be possible.

## Examples

```
x = x + a + b;  ==>  x += a + b;  /* this implies a different order of evaluation */
x = x + a * b;  ==>  x += a * b;
x = x + a % b;  ==>  x += a % b;  /* % has higher precedence than + */
```

**Note [1]:** well, you can, but using another operator, the `,` comma operator, you can convert it to `x += 1, x %= 10;`